# ion-content does not allow to push an Object. Showing undefined

Tags: ionic-framework

I am getting some issue while working with ionic framework. I am trying to work on Grocery app Where user can add items. The code which I have written doesn't work showing "undefined" with blank field and But when I replace "ion-content" tag with "div" tag then My code works fine. I am confused why is this happening? Please help Thanks.

```
<ion-content> 
        <div class="grocery-wrapper">
            <ion-item    ng-repeat="groceryItem in groceryItems">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col col-20">
                        <label class="checkbox checkbox-balanced">
                            <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox"/>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col col-33 g-items">{{groceryItem.itemName}}</div>
                    <div class="col g-items">{{groceryItem.Quantity}}</div>
                    <div class="col g-items">{{groceryItem.Rate}} rs/kg</div>
                </div>
            </ion-item>

            <div id="getGroceryItem" ng-show="GroceryItem">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col col-50">
                        <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
                           <span class="input-label">Grocery Item</span>
                           <input ng-model="gItem" type="text" placeholder="Grocery Item">
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
                            <span class="input-label">Kg</span>
                            <input ng-model="gKg" type="text" placeholder="kg">
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
                            <span class="input-label">Price</span>
                            <input ng-model="gPrice" type="text" placeholder="Price">
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <button class="button button-block button-balanced button-medium" ng-click="addGroceryItem()">
                        ADD ITEM 
                    </button>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
      </ion-content>
```

---

```
app.controller('getGrocery', function($scope){
    //console.log("Grocery Items");
    $scope.groceryItems = [
        {
        'itemName':'Rice',
        'Quantity':'5kg',
        'Rate':'50'
        },
        {
        'itemName':'Wheat',
        'Quantity':'6kg',
        'Rate':'44'
        }
    ];

    //Hide show elemment
    $scope.GroceryItem = false;

    $scope.addGroceryItem = function() {
        //$scope.groceryObj = {}; 
        $scope.groceryItems.push(
            {
                itemName:$scope.gItem,
                Quantity:$scope.gKg,
                Rate:$scope.gPrice
            }
        ); 
        console.log($scope.gItem)   
        console.log($scope.gKg) 
        console.log($scope.gPrice)  

        $scope.gItem = "";
        $scope.gKg = "";
        $scope.gPrice = "";
    }
})
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1at2T.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per reference http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/14/nested-scopes-in-angularjs.html

**Angular Scopes and Prototypes.**

AngularJS will often create child scopes inside of directives, for the same reasons we saw above: it allows a directive to have it’s own space for key/value pairs, without messing with higher level data. Child scopes inherit from parent scopes using prototypal inheritance. (There is an exception for isolated scopes);

But we often do want to transparently write to a higher level scope, and this is where the “dot rule” comes in. Let’s see how that is applied.

Do not do this

// Controller

```
$scope.gItem = "Test"
```

// HTML

```
<input ng-model="gItem">
```

That is bad because we can’t write to it from a child scope, because a child scope uses prototypal inheritance. Once you write to gItem from a child scope, it would become a distinct value in that child scope, and no longer refer up to the parent’s gItem.

Instead, do this

// Controller

```
$scope.newItem   = {
        gItem:  "",
        gKg:  "",
        gPrice:  "",
    }
```

// HTML

```
<input ng-model="newItem.gItem">
```

The difference is we are not storing the data directly on the scope. Now when ng-model wants to write, it actually does a read, then write. It reads the newItem property from the scope, and this will work from a child scope because a child scope will search upwards for a read. Once it finds newItem, it writes to newItem.gItem, which is no problem. It just works

Index.html should be

```
<body ng-app="grocery">

<ion-pane ng-controller="getGrocery">
  <ion-header-bar class="bar bar-header bar-assertive">
    <h1 class="title text-center">Grocery</h1>
    <button class="button" ng-click="GroceryItem=!GroceryItem" ng-class="{active:GroceryItem}">
        <i class="icon ion-android-add"></i>
    </button>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-content class="grocery-wrapper"> 
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item ng-repeat="groceryItem in groceryItems">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col col-20">
                    <label class="checkbox checkbox-balanced">
                        <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox"/>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="col col-33 g-items">{{groceryItem.itemName}}</div>
                <div class="col g-items">{{groceryItem.Quantity}}</div>
                <div class="col g-items">{{groceryItem.Rate}} rs/kg</div>
            </div>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item id="getGroceryItem" ng-show="GroceryItem">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col col-50">
                    <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
                       <span class="input-label">Grocery Item</span>
                       <input ng-model="newitem.gItem" type="text" placeholder="Grocery Item">
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
                        <span class="input-label">Kg</span>
                        <input ng-model="newitem.gKg" type="text" placeholder="kg">
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
                        <span class="input-label">Price</span>
                        <input ng-model="newitem.gPrice" type="text" placeholder="Price">
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <button class="button button-block button-balanced button-medium" ng-click="addGroceryItem()">
                    ADD ITEM 
                </button>
            </div>

        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-pane>
```

app.js should be

```
app.controller('getGrocery', function($scope){
//console.log("Grocery Items");
$scope.groceryItems = [
    {
    'itemName':'Rice',
    'Quantity':'5kg',
    'Rate':'50'
    },
    {
    'itemName':'Wheat',
    'Quantity':'6kg',
    'Rate':'44'
    }
];

//Hide show elemment
$scope.GroceryItem = false;


$scope.newitem   = {
    gItem:  "",
    gKg:  "",
    gPrice:  "",
}

$scope.addGroceryItem = function() {
    //$scope.groceryObj = {}; 
    console.log($scope.newitem.gItem)
    console.log($scope.newitem.gKg)
    console.log($scope.newitem.gPrice)
    $scope.groceryItems.push(
        {
            itemName:$scope.newitem.gItem,
            Quantity:$scope.newitem.gKg,
            Rate:$scope.newitem.gPrice
        }
    ); 

    $scope.newitem   = {
        gItem:  "",
        gKg:  "",
        gPrice:  "",
    }

}
```

});